# ASP.Net table width not being displayed correctly

Tags: html, css, asp.net

EDIT: If anyone else is looking for this solution, check the comments under the answer marked as correct.  Using div tags and inline-block got everything displaying correctly.

I'm trying to get a table to take up 60% of the available space.  Nothing seems to change what is being displayed...the table row is taking up 100% (or more) of the available space and not wrapping the elements to the next row.  All the data is correct, the formatting just won't take.

Anyone able to help me figure out why the width isn't being respected?

CSS:

```
/*#region project-data */

.project-data {
    width: 60%;
}

.project-alert {
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #999;
}

.project-alert th {
    text-align: center;
}

.al-text {
}

.info-bar {
    height: 8px;
}

.last-reported {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: small;
}

.al-time {
    font-size: small;
}

/*#endregion */
```

Partial View:

```
<table class="project-data">
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <td>
                <table class="project-alert">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @item.TypeText
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td class="al-text">@item.AlertText</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="info-bar" style="background-color:@item.InfoBar"></td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="last-reported">Last Reported</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="al-time">@item.AlertTime</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is your table in some sort of container with fixed width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the width is not being respected in your case is that you have `nested tables`. Just change your html to something simple like:

```
 <table class="project-data">
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
                <tr>                       
                    <td> @item.TypeText <td>                           
                </tr>                   

                    <tr><td class="al-text">@item.AlertText</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="info-bar" style="background-color:@item.InfoBar"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="last-reported">Last Reported</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="al-time">@item.AlertTime</td></tr>


    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can refer to this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3mocxwh/) to see how a simple structure table will respond to the width you are trying to give.

Comment: I'm going to have 7 separate @items, and I'd like each to be organized like this...one after another left-to-right, and wrapping at the end of the line.  I guess maybe if I could organize it in columns I could make it work, but it's not ideal, since if we change the number of our alerts later the table won't display properly.

Comment: why don't you try without a table? Use div tags instead. Something like:

   <div>
         <!-- repeat divs here (keeping display as inline block) -->
    </div>

Here is a sample [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcj0bmnw/)

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much for the help!  Just a little more tweaking and I'm all the way there.